# Nomethod error in the show template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## show.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  <h1><strong>Title</strong></h1> 
  <%= post.Title.upcase %>
  <h2><i>name</i></h2>
  <%= post.Name.capitalize %>
  <p>
  <b>Message</b>
  <%=post.Message %>
  </p>
<% end -%>
```

## post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts =Post.all
  end

  def new
    @posts =Post.new  
  end
  
  def create#no view just for the saving process
    @posts = Post.new(ok_params)
    if @posts.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show#we will use it to view the whole mesage
    @posts=Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @posts=Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @posts=Post.find(params[:id])
    if @posts.update_attributes(ok_params)
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @posts=Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts.destroy
      
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def ok_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:Title, :Name, :Message, :Comments)
  end
end
```

But when the app run in the server(which i use thin instead of puma) it indicates a NoMethod error of "unidentified method ##each"
[the NoMethod error in the show template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmPJe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in your show action you are setting your @posts variable to a single Post instance, not an Enumerable collection. So it cannot be iterated over with a `#each`.

in your show you are only wanting to display a single Post, yes? if so, you do not need to use .each, just change your show to:

```
<h1><strong>Title</strong></h1> 
<%= @post.Title.upcase %>
<h2><i>name</i></h2>
<%= @post.Name.capitalize %>
<p>
  <b>Message</b>
  <%= @post.Message %>
</p>
```

and change your controllers show action to:

```
def show # we will use it to view the whole mesage
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

use the singular instead of the plural, as you are assigning just a single instance.